# Saving PDF/Picture to Kubernetes configmap and retrieving it in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, configmap

I have a requirement to store pdf in kubernetes configmap and then retrieve it in springboot application for further processing.
I have created a configmap using the pdf using
`oc create configmap testpdf --from-file=datafile.pdf`.
Now I have the configmap with the Base64 encoded data of the pdf which I have mounted as volume mount. Also, I have experienced that when I try to access that configmap, it is automatically decodes back to byte stream from Base64(Please Correct me if I am wrong).
Now in my springboot application retrieving the configmap data using.

```
    @Value(${datafile.pdf})
    byte[] pdfdata;

    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> retrievePDF() {
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
       headers.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + "terms_conditions.pdf\"");
       headers.setContentLength(pdfdata.length);
       return new ResponseEntity<>(pdfdata, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Now when I hit the controller, I am getting a blank white pdf, although the pdf that is saved in configmap is perfectly fine. The Base64 encoded value in the configmap is correct too(I have checked that using Base64 to pdf online too).

Requesting to please help. I am stuck into this for last one week.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the method like this:

```java
byte[] pdfData = ...


HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);

headers.setContentDispositionFormData("terms_conditions.pdf", "terms_conditions.pdf");
headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        
return response;
```

It should work if your  pdfData array really represents your PDF.

Comment: Hi Mihailo,  Tried your suggestion. Still the same blank pdf getting downloded. I think that the byte array that i am getting from configmap is getting modified while retrieving or there should be some other way to store the byte stream of pdf that is coming from configmap. Any suggestion or any other way??Please help.

Comment: Yes, then it is definitely related to config map (and its storing of pdf). Let me try to understand: You want to have a config map, where one config property is i.e. `pdf : <base64data>`. And with your java code you want to access that property that represents the pdf? I think that command that you have in the question should be used to create the whole config map and parameter `--from-file` should accept `yaml`. I could check tomorrow, it sounds as interesting problem in general

Comment: Yes that is what the configmap is storing ~pdf:<base64data>~. And while retrieving, it is decoding back and then giving us the value. The command that i used is to create the configmap directly from the pdf file and not using yaml. With this command what i get is a configmap which has content as "<pdf file name> : <base64data>" so this pdf file name can be used as the key to fetch its value. Hope you understood. Please help me on this.